# Inner Join com Where e múltiplas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, join, inner-join

Estou montando uma query, onde preciso fazer join entre duas tabelas (pois o dado estará na principal B mas não na complementar BC) e uma terceira tabela que obrigatoriamente preciso dos dados, que sempre estarão na tabela principal B.

Tentei conforme abaixo, mas retorna erro de sintaxe. Pesquisei aqui mesmo e não encontrei um exemplo, alguma sugestão?

```
select DATE_FORMAT(b.dt_lancamento, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_lancamento_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(b.dt_abertura, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_abertura_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(b.dt_finalizacao, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_finalizacao_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(b.dt_prim_producao, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_prim_producao_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_solicitacao, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_solicitacao_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_alergenico_ti, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_alergenico_ti_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_auto_avaliacao_ti, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_auto_avaliacao_ti_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_cert_halal, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_cert_halal_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_cert_kosher, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_cert_kosher_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_cert_brc, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_cert_brc_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_cert_fssc, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_cert_fssc_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_cert_ifs, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_cert_ifs_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_controle_pragas, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_controle_pragas_F,
                      DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_apro_fornecedor, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_apro_fornecedor_F
                      u.admin NIVEL, BC.*,B.*
                 FROM USUARIOS U,
                      BRIEFING B
                LEFT JOIN BRIEFING_COMPRAS BC ON bc.cod = b.cod
                WHERE B.responsavel = u.nome_completo
                  AND B.COD = 551
```

Comment: Qual o erro de sintaxe? Informe qual o erro que ocorre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faltava uma vírgula depois da declaração de um dos campos:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(b.dt_lancamento, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_lancamento_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(b.dt_abertura, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_abertura_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(b.dt_finalizacao, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_finalizacao_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(b.dt_prim_producao, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_prim_producao_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_solicitacao, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_solicitacao_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_alergenico_ti, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_alergenico_ti_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_auto_avaliacao_ti, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_auto_avaliacao_ti_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_cert_halal, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_cert_halal_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_cert_kosher, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_cert_kosher_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_cert_brc, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_cert_brc_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_cert_fssc, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_cert_fssc_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_cert_ifs, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_cert_ifs_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_controle_pragas, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_controle_pragas_F,
       DATE_FORMAT(bc.dt_apro_fornecedor, '%d-%m-%Y') as dt_apro_fornecedor_F,
       u.admin NIVEL,
       BC.*,
       B.*
  FROM USUARIOS U
 INNER JOIN BRIEFING B ON B.responsavel = u.nome_completo
  LEFT JOIN BRIEFING_COMPRAS BC ON bc.cod = b.cod
 WHERE B.COD = 551
```

Comment: Tive que tirar a vírgula depois da tabela Usuarios, ai deu certo. Muito obrigado!